# How to split a string by certain length in excel and put it into columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

In excel 2016 I want to split a single string with no separators into a 2-character cell under column A (same column). The string has no fixed length.

Example AAB4101X -> AA | B4 | 10 | 1X
Example single string in the cell AAB4101X ->

Desired column:
AA
B4
10
1X

Additional question:
Will the formula work with Japanese characters?

Example:戦略聞く中国　->
Desired column:
戦略
聞く
中国

I would appreciate any suggestion as well.

Answer (score 0):

**::Caveat::**

*Below show method addresses *only the first part* of the question.
So readers please do not consider this for the other text is in `Japanese language`.*

*Since I'm unable to reproduce the text in `Japanese language`, therefore I've skipped it.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Put helper data are in Red, in range C136:G136
- If the string's length is 8 only, then you may skip Helper Data in Cell G136.
- For neatness later on you may hide Helper data.
- Formula in cell C137 ( fill it across ) :

  `=MID($A137,COLUMN()+C$136-COLUMN($C137)+1,2)`

**N.B.**

- You may adjust the cell references in the formula as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Presenting a **generalised solution** for any string and any Split Length.------

STEP 1 : Give titles in Row 1 : A1 = “String”, B1 =”Length”, C1 = “Split Length”,   D1=1, E1= D1+1,... Copy the formula of E1, right across ------ So as to get Series : 1, 2, 3, 4,5,....D1 Onwards****************

STEP 2 : First Third row, Enter the given String say “ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ” in A3;  In B3 write formula B3 = LEN(A3),..it will be giving length of string, here 17, ......, In C3 enter the desired Split Length; in our ex. It is 2 ; So enter value 2 in C3

STEP 3 : Now in Second Row ; write formula in D2,  = $C$3*D1, after this Copy the formula of Cell D2, right across. In our case you will get 2,4,6,8..****

STEP 4 : Formula in Cell D3 = LEFT($A$3,C3)-----------to get “AB” ****

STEP 5 : Enter Formula in E3 = MID($A$3,D2+1,$C$3)----------*****
STEP 6 : Copy the formula of E3, right across in 3rd row.....to get desired result. As
“AB”, “CD”,  “EF” .....  etc.

Note : Now change the split length; say 3. So enter 3 in Cell C3 the results would be :
“ABC”, “DEF”, “GHI” etc. Like that Enter 1 to get A, B, C, D..... Enter 4 in C3 to get : ABCD, EFGH, IJKL...etc.****** Any string, any split length will work.

Thanks for giving the opportunity to think.

Comment: Please [edit] your post & add some screen shot to justify what you have done !!

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer can be improved to eliminate need for helper data by using column relationships to calculate starting point for MID function.

Original formula:
=MID($A137,COLUMN()+C$136-COLUMN($C137)+1,2)
the C$136 was where the helper data is stored.

Better formula:
=MID($A137,(COLUMN() - COLUMN($C137)*2 + 1,2)

Comment: Your formula needs little correction & it should `=MID($A137,COLUMN() - COLUMN($C137)*2 + 1,2)`,, but even though returns #VALUE error !!